# How do I download a 7GB tensorflow-dataset in Google Colab without ending the 12 hour limit?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-datasets, machine-translation

I'm trying to download the **wmt14_translate/fr-en** dataset from **TensorFlow-datasets** in Google Colab under the free tier. Downloading the dataset itself is taking me over 12 hours. Is there any alternative using Google Drive or something since I already have the data stored on my laptop.

PS - The file format of the dataset isn't really clear since it does not even end with a '.'.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihfqP.png)[enter image description here]

Comment: you can mount your google drive.

Answer (score 0):

Upload the dataset to google drive.

Then, in colab,

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Comment: AssertionError: Dataset wmt14_translate: could not find data in /content/drive/My\ Drive/. Please make sure to call dataset_builder.download_and_prepare(), or pass download=True to tfds.load() before trying to access the tf.data.Dataset object. This is the issue. It works fine on my Mac though

Comment: This seems a separate issue, why are you again downloading? You should download first and upload to google drive.

Comment: dataset = tfds.load(name='wmt14_translate/fr-en', as_supervised=True, download=False, data_dir="/content/drive/My\ Drive/")
The download option is false, so it should be using the data_dir but it doesn't and throws that error

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wget` to download datasets. Downloading by `wget` utility is much faster than uploading.

Also, if you'll use kaggle dataset someday you can use `kaggle datasets download`.

Comment: The load function looks for a particular type of folder and on providing it, this is the error - AssertionError: Dataset wmt14_translate: could not find data in /content/drive/My\ Drive/. Please make sure to call dataset_builder.download_and_prepare(), or pass download=True to tfds.load() before trying to access the tf.data.Dataset object.